# Locale only set partially

Tags: locale

When I set my locale using `update-locale LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8` the content of `/etc/default/locale` gets updated accordingly. The changes are also reflected my shell's environment variables, but executing `locale` shows all as

```
max@wilma ~$ locale                                                     13:39:08
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

What's happening there?

Comment: I posted an answer, but now i see something else. You have set `LC_ALL` persistently in a config file. Remove that `LC_ALL` entry, whereever you set it.

Comment: Actually the .pam_environement didn't affect anything at all, while the LC_ALL was the problem.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson: So what about posting the LC_ALL part as an answer?

Comment: Just posted the LC_ALL observation as an answer.

Comment: Just accepted that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `locale` output I see that you have set `LC_ALL` persistently in a config file. Remove that `LC_ALL` entry, whereever you set it.

Comment: Gunnar, +1 on both answers..I am missing some string though..isn't the output of `locale` shows the values that are active? if so then why isn't OP's change isn't showing in `locale` output and at the same time the change is applied perfectly as OP has confirmed that too..

Comment: @heemayl: It's because `LC_ALL` overrides individual settings of other `LC_*` variables when the `locale` command evaluates what's the effective value. `LC_ALL` should never, ever be set persistently on an Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: That means `locale` is not perfect..is there any possible way to get absolute status of locale parameters without reading any files ?

Comment: @heemayl: `locale` does exactly what it's supposed to do, AFAICT. You can check the value of respective environment value, e.g. `echo $LC_TIME`, but those values are irrelevant as long as `LC_ALL` is set (which it, as already said, should not be).

Answer (score 1):

If you ever has used a GUI for setting language and/or regional formats, your user specific settings (which override the system wide settings in `/etc/default/locale`) have been saved in `~/.pam_environement`. The best way to prevent surprising behavior is to keep using the GUIs, especially [Language Support](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/prefs-language.html), for handling languages and locales.

Comment: Actually I'm not eager to use GUI as long as I don't MUST, because of such inconsistencies. Besides, you'll never know if your Linux has a GUI at all.

Comment: @MaxRied: I wouldn't agree on "inconsistencies". And this is an Ubuntu resource... But right, I know there are a few of you Linux guys who are comfortable with the command line and prefer to do things that way. I respect that too. ;)